# Monitoring an existing file with fsnotify

Tags: string, go, go-fsnotify

I'm trying to monitor a file using the fsnotify packet in golang.

I saw few examples like this and I would like to know if this is the best way of using fsnotify:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/howeyc/fsnotify"
)

func main() {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    done := make(chan bool)

    // Process events
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case ev := <-watcher.Event:
                log.Println("event:", ev)
            case err := <-watcher.Error:
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = watcher.Watch("testDir")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    <-done

    var get_info := []string
    get_info = read_file(path_to_file) 


    watcher.Close()
}
```

Basically I'm passing a path where the file is located and geting the resul in a string variable.

Everytime I change the file I would like to read the file and get the result.

I'm not sure if I'm using fsnotify correctly base on that example. Also, I'm not sure where to put the file path in the fsnotify to monitor that file.

Answer (score 3):

You're leveraging fsnotify pretty much correctly, the only change would likely be that you want to utilize the channel to grab events and then use the event to extract the file name that changed. This would allow you to monitor multiple files and also in your example I don't believe you ever pass a value into done for it to properly finish waiting on the channel and read the file contents.

I'm adding a simple sample below that gets rid of the go routine and simply listens for changes on the main thread.

```
func main() {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()

    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    err = watcher.Add("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    for {
            select {
            case ev := <-watcher.Events:
                    log.Println("event:", ev)
                    if ev.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                            contents, err := ioutil.ReadFile(ev.Name)
                            if err != nil {
                                // handle error
                            }
                            log.Println("modified file:", string(contents))
                    }
            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                    log.Println("error:", err)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your message. Regarding the code I have some questions. If the file path is for example “/etc/file.txt” I can include that path in watcher.add, isn’t? Also, this code will be executed one time and later will keep monitoring for changes on “file.txt”? Last question, rest of my code, functions, routines will go where you put “ log.Println("modified file:", string(contents))”, right?

Comment: 1. That is correct, you would use watcher.add to listen for changes on a file path
2. Also correct, the final for loop, will essentially loop infinitely listening for changes and the select {} statement will wait for watcher to either send an event or an error, this prevents the loop from wasting CPU
3. Yes, instead of printing out the file contents you could for example send the file name to a function you write that then performs some operations on the file

Comment: I managed the code. I had to create a "go.mod" file to import the fsnotify as was throwing some errors without that. Also, I noticed that the fsnotify code block is not reading the file the first time unless you modify something there. That's not a solution in my case as I have to read the file the first time as well.